# How to estimate filter coefficients of an all-pole system?

Tags: filters, estimation, infinite-impulse-response

Suppose we have measured the frequency response of a system that is known to be all-pole; measuring impulse response is not possible. What are the methods available, if any, to estimate the coefficients of the underlying IIR filter?

EDIT: Frequency response exists only as measured data, so closed mathematical expression is not available, nor is the phase information.

Comment: Does the measured frequency response include phase information?

Comment: Do you have any closed form expression for the frequency response? or  you have only samples of the frequency response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Half of the information about a system is in the phase response, and half of it in the amplitude response. There's no way to reconstruct a filter if you know only either half, unless you strongly restrict the poles mathematically.

Comment: Supposing one did have the phase information available, what would be the method to reconstruct the filter?

Comment: 1. restrict how many poles you can have. 2. find out whether your filter is stable for harmonic excitation (poles all within unit circle?), 3. be $y[n] = x[n]*h[n]$ (discrete filter $h$ convoluted with signal $x$), calc the z-transform of both sides of that equation, divide by $X$. 4. inverse z-Transform of $H$